# Why my session is getting lost on calling a base

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session

I'm loosing my session when I call the base method, is there a reason to get null session?

here is my controller action

```
public class SystemAdminController : BaseController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string removeItems)
    {         
      //Session["storedevices"] <<<< my session data is still avail    
      RemoveItemFromGrid(removeItems); //<<< as soon as I call this method my Session get lost why?     
    }     
 }

public class BaseController : Controller
{
   public void RemoveItemFromGrid(string items)
   {
       //Session["storedevices"] //Session is null/lost here?
       //to do
   }
}
```

Comment: Just try to wrap your every sessions with `HttpContext.Current.Session[key]` and try

Answer (score 0):

There's something strange going on with your code. It should work just fine.

Some things to help you to debug:

- Make sure you are not trying to access `Session["storedevices"]` on the `BaseController` before the `Controller.Session` property is actually populated. For instance, it's supposed to be null on the Controller's constructor. It's only available after the `Initialize` method, if I can remember well.
- Make sure `this.Session == base.Session`. For some reason, you might be "newing" the `Session` property in the descendant Controller. Just put a breakpoint there and make sure this expression is true.
- Make sure `this.Session == System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session` both in the descendant Controller and in the base Controller.

Comment: I'm accessing `Session["storedevices"]` on the `BaseController` as I have posted the code above `RemoveItemFromGrid`so what should I do in the `BaseController` initialize?